# Watch files outside the current directory using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Is there a way to detect changes outside the current directory using pm2? For example on `/home/sprguillen/workspace/node` I have an **index.js** which is the script to be ran by **pm2**. Now I have a configuration file outside it located on `/home/sprguillen/workspace/config`. I have my own reasons not to put it inside the node directory such as the possibility of having different node applications to access the same configuration file. Is this possible using pm2 that any changes found on say `/home/sprguillen/workspace/config` will be included by the *watch*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/development-tools/#watch-options) you can configure `watch` option in the `ecosystem.config.js` to monitor multiple paths. So you can try something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./index.js",
    watch: [
        ".",
        "../config",
    ],
  }]
}
```

And run your app from the same directory as `ecosystem.config.js`: `pm2 start`