# Can I watch files outside of current directory with `npm run watch`?

Tags: watch, cucumberjs, npm-watch

I work with two repo's; one with source code and one with E2E tests using CucumberJS:

1. application-repo/
2. application-e2e/

I would like to run `npm run watch` in the second repo and wait for changes to files in the first repo; because I want to have my CucumberJS tests run on changes to the source-code. The place I work dictate me not to have the e2e-tests in the same repo, as the source code.

Similar question, but with `pm2` instead of `npm-watch` / `watch`:
[Watch files outside the current directory using pm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758018/watch-files-outside-the-current-directory-using-pm2)

Answer (score 0):

It was a lot easier than I thought, at least when using `watch` and not `npm-watch`, but probably both can be used the same way.

Here's my `package.json` of the second repo:

```
{
  "name": "application-e2e",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch":"watch 'echo hello' ../application-repo/", // First repo

  (...)
```

When running `npm run watch` in the second repo, changes made in the first repo will make it write `hello` in the terminal of the second repo.